# wsprintf() crashes my application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, type-conversion

I'm new to this site, so if I get something wrong in my first post, please don't take it so hard on me.

Here goes nothing...

In my application, I have the following code:

`wsprintf(hardware_info, "%ul+%ul", dwGPU, dwCPU);`

`hardware_info` is stored as a LPSTR, and is passed by reference as a parameter to the function which contains this line (e.g. `void do_something(IN LPSTR out){}`)

`dwGPU` and `dwCPU` are obviously `DWORD` or `ul, unsigned long` data types.

When this application is executed it crashes right after executing the above line of code (note, it doesn't get passed this line). Can someone explain to me what the problem is?

EDIT:

I've fixed the issue. I believe it was more of a logical error.
I confused `%ul` as I thought it stood for `unsigned long`, though through some research I've learned that it's actually `%lu`, strangely enough.

Thanks to anyone who contributed to this, it's really helped get my thoughts going.

Comment: How is `hardware_info`  declared? How do you allocate memory for the target buffer?

Comment: I think I allocated enough assuming the maximum possible length of the buffer is 64 bytes. I've used `memset(hardware_info, 0, 4096);` and then `realloc()` `4096 - sizeof(hardware_info)` after the buffer has been filled. I move that allocation to the end of the buffer and then use some assembly logic to store the current buffer into the newly allocated frame. So I don't think it's a problem here... Also, I can't believe how many trolls there is in stackoverflow. I purposely say "Im new here, take it easy on me", and moments later I get -3 rep on my FIRST question".

Comment: You're doing a lot of describing, but not actually showing us the code that allocates that space.  For the heck of it, just declare `hardware_info` as a simple run-of-the-mill buffer that holds 1000 characters -- no fancy logic to figure out how large to make it.  If you did that, does the program crash?

Comment: Yes. It still crashes.

Comment: Can you post *exactly* what you're doing?  There is no issue running this program when compiled as an MBCS program (Visual Studio 2013):  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5f6693c119e4b7d

Comment: @ilan_portman `hardware_info is stored as a LPSTR, and is passed by reference `  So you pass a reference to a pointer?  You really need to post your code, as the description doesn't seem to add up.  Also, that small program stores `0l+0l` in hardware_info, so `ul` doesn't seem to be a format specifier (`u` is, but not `ul`)

Answer (score 1):

Well, firstly, if your `hardware_info` is `LPSTR`, then why are you using `wsprintf`? `wsprintf` is for `LPTSTR`. `LPSTR` is a "regular" char pointer that is supposed to work with `sprintf`. Your format string is also a regular string, that is supposed to work with `sprintf`. Your code will compile and work as is (i.e. with `wsprintf`), if the project is set up for narrow-character strings, but still there's no logic in using `wsprintf` here.

Secondly, I'd guess that you failed to allocate memory for your `hardware_info` or did not allocate enough. This might be what caused your code to crash.

Comment: `sprintf()` doesn't make a difference, it still crashes. And since everyone tries to act like such a smart ass here... If you looked closer at the WinAPI constricts. It goes like this `typedef LPSTR LPTSTR` -- So please, it's not like it matters whether I use `wsprintf()` or `sprintf()`. Although, thank-you for trying, I'd like a real an answer from someone else, anyone?

Comment: Also, to add on to the comment above. `typedef LPSTR LPTSTR`, and `typedef CHAR* LPSTR`. Therefore https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550%28v=vs.85%29.aspxx (refer to the first prototype). `sprintf()` takes `typedef char* PCHAR` as the first parameter. Therefore using LPTSTR as a parameter to this function is the same as https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx

Comment: `And since everyone tries to act like such a smart ass here..`  I see nothing wrong in the way the answer was given to you.  I think you need to calm down a little.

Comment: @ilan_portman: Apparently you didn't look close enough. If you look closer at WinAPI declarations, you will see that `LPTSTR` is defined as **either** `LPSTR` **or** `LPWSTR` depending on your project settings. The same is true for `wsprintf` - it resolves to either `sprintf` or `swprintf` depending on project settings. If you want to create a "polymprphic" MSVC project, that can switch between narrow and wide chars, stick to `LPTSTR` and `wsprintf`. If you want a regular char project, stick to `LPSTR` and `sprintf`. Your current mix of the two makes no sense.

Comment: If your project is set up for narrow chars, then `wsprintf` becomes equivalent to `sprintf`. Your code is correct in that case, which is what I said in my answer. However, that does not mean that your mix of "polymorphic" function `wsprintf` and "non-polymorphic" type `LPSTR` is appropriate.